# Finder restore window error

Tags: osx-lion, finder

My mac with Lion starts up with the finder displaying the message to "Restore Windows" and keep on cycling through it but never opening the Finder windows. Other sites say that files in my desktop folder is corrupt and I must delete them with terminal. There is no way to open the terminal app in my normal user profile.

I have created a test user profile with administrative rights and that works fine but the problem is my normal desktop folder is locked and not accessible in my test user account. How do is delete those files in my normal desktop folder with the terminal app?

Comment: **Please** put **some** effort into how you write your question if you want people to read it and help you.

Comment: Voting to close. I can't make out what the question is.

Comment: my problem is that the mac finder does not open it gives an error mesage "restore window" and does not mater what button i klick it returns with the same error message "restore window". i can open programs in my dock but cant get into my hard drive because finder does not open!

Answer (score 0):

According to [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/message/15671196) on Apple Support (edited for clarity):

- Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> to open the "Force Quit" window
- Click on "Finder", and then select "Relaunch"

[image]

If that doesn't work, and you're able to open Terminal, type `killall Finder` at the prompt, like so:

```
corne:mac.local corne$ killall Finder
```

This should force Finder to die and restart.